# If then join else other join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, if-statement

I am trying to figure out a query which joins several tables (cca 8). At one point I need to join one of two tables. So lets call the result until this point A. Now I want to join B, or C. When I use B, I get smaller result, or no result. If there is no result after the join, I need to join C instead.

To summarize, intersection of (A,C) gives bigger result and I only want to join C if intersection of (A,B) is empty.

What would be a smooth way to say this in mysql?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Only join if the first join primary key is null:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN C ON B.id IS NULL AND A.id = C.id
```

Comment: If you want the results of B or C to appear in the same columns in your select list, you can use something like `SELECT coalesce(B.id, C.id) as id, coalesce(B.othercolumnname, C.othercolumnname) as othercolumnname, ...`.

Comment: thank you both, that's exactly the idea I've been looking for